# Accessing an array outside of a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function that grabs the distinct digits in a given array of integers. I stored the distinct digits in another array, but I would like to access the distinct digits outside of `getUncommon` so that I can do some comparing and sorting.

Would this be possible without the use of global variables in C++?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getUncommon(int* iAry, int size) {
    const int size2 = 10;
    int* tmpAry = new int[size2];
    int totalCount[size2] = { 0 };
    int currentCount[size2] = { 0 };
    int totalUncommon = 0;
    int i, j;
    int rareDigits[size2] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tmpAry[i] = iAry[i];
        if (tmpAry[i] < 0)
            tmpAry[i] *= -1;

        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++)
            currentCount[j] = 0;

        if (tmpAry[i] == 0) {
            currentCount[0] = 1;
        }

        while (tmpAry[i] / 10 != 0 || tmpAry[i] % 10 != 0){
            currentCount[tmpAry[i] % 10] = 1;
            tmpAry[i] /= 10;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            totalCount[j] += currentCount[j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        if (totalCount[i] == 1) {
            totalUncommon++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Total of uncommon digits: " << totalUncommon << endl
        << "Uncommon digits:\n";
    if (totalUncommon == 0) {
        cout << "\nNo uncommon digits found.";
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            if (totalCount[i] == 1) {
                cout << i << endl;
                rareDigits[i] = totalCount[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

int getNumRareDigits(int x) {
    // I would like to access rareDigits
    // so that I can pass in an integer
    // and see if it contains rareDigits[i] to
    // find the total number of rare digits.
}

int main(){
    int* my_arry;
    int size;
    int i;

    cout << "How many integers? ";
    cin >> size;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter values #" << i << " : ";
        cin >> size;
    }


    cout << "\nThe original array:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << my_arry[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nCalling function -\n" << endl;

    getUncommon(my_arry, size);


    return 0;
}
```

How can I access `rareDigits[i]` outside of `getUncommon`?

Comment: "I stored the distinct digits [of array `A`] in another array [called `B`], but I would like to access the distinct digits **[`A` or `B`?]** outside of `foo()` so that I can do some comparing and sorting."

Comment: 1. Use a global variable or 2. Define rareDigits in main() and then pass it into the other functions.

Comment: My suggestion - simply to return a vector (of rare digits) from getUncommon. Or, if you want to sort them, a set.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the real heart of the problem is that you want to access a local variable from an external scope. Without using a global, your primary means is to pass in the array you want to fill.

For example, getUncommon might now look like this:

```
void getUncommon(int* iAry, int size, int* rare, int rareSize) { ...
```

Now a problem that you may have to think about in the future is what to do if the "rare" array's size is not known upfront. To solve this, you may either want to use an int** (allocating the array in getUncommon) or more likely to use something like a std::vector&.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through pass by reference.

```
void getUncommon(int* iAry, int size, int *outArr, int &outSize) //&outSize make it pass by reference
{
    outArr[0] = 1;
    outArr[1] = 2;
    outSize = 2;   //Address of outSize and address of outSz same, so they both hold same value
}

int main()
{

    int my_arry[10], outArr[10];
    int outSz, size;

    getUncommon(my_arry, size, outArr, outSz);
    cout<<outSz<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<outSz; i++)
    {
        cout<<outArr[i]<<" ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here your `outArr` should be fill up  within `getUncommon` function and size of array return through `outSz`.

**Your code have some other problem which show's UB**.

You declare pointer as

```
int* my_arry;
```

but you don't allocate memory. To allocate memory you can use

```
my_arry = new int[10];
```

after using free the memory

```
delete []my_arry;
```